# Trigger FireFox extensions from a custom button

Tags: javascript, triggers, firefox-addon

I have converted some Chrome extensions to firefox .xpi and installed them in FF. 
They show up in the add ons list but how can I make a custom button somewhere in a toolbar and  trigger the extension?

In Chrome you have a specific toolbar that shows the extensions… and To trigger them.

Cheers,

M

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the addon SDK do something like this:

```
//WIDGET METAINFO
var meta_info = widgets.Widget({
    id: "meta_info",
  label: "Displays information about Meta",
  contentURL: data.url("icons/meta.png"),
  panel: meta_panel
});
var meta_panel = panel.Panel({
  width: 500,
  height: 300,
  contentURL: data.url("html/meta.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("js/meta_panel.js"),
  onShow: function()
  {
      get_metas();
  }
});
```

if you want to do bootstrap see these templates here, you can install the xpi to see it in action:

- [_template-ff-addon-BootstrapURLIconWidget.xpi](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9266173)

I'm making more templates let me know if there's one you would like to see.

Comment: This other user posted his SDK source code [HERE](https://github.com/Rob--W/toolbarwidget-jplib)